# C - How to Iterate through sub-nodes in a linked list?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, nodes

I have the following program which I'm developing:

```
...

typedef struct node_tag{
    int id;
    char pLabel[10];
    struct node_tag *pNext;
    struct node_tag *pInner;
    }NODE;

...

int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {

    NODE *list = create_node("start");
    add_node(&list, "MUSIC");
    add_node(&list, "VIDEOS");
    add_node(&list, "PICTURES");
    create_sub_node( &list, "2015" ); // sub node of PICTURES
    create_sub_node( &list, "Trip" ); // sub node of 2015
    print_nodes(list);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
```

**Output:**

```
|
|-> [ID:4] PICTURES
|   |-> [ID:40] 2015
|   |   |-> [ID:400] Trip
|
|-> [ID:3] VIDEOS
|
|-> [ID:2] MUSIC
|
|-> [ID:1] start
|
```

Everything works as I want so far, as can be seen on the output. However I want to implement different methodology of creating sub nodes. What I've got now is very limited as it can only create the depth of 2 sub nodes but I want to have unlimited depth:

```
void create_sub_node( NODE **handle, char* label )
    {
    NODE *new = malloc( sizeof(NODE) );

    new->pNext = NULL;
    new->pInner = NULL;
    strncpy( new->pLabel , label , strlen(label) +1 );   

    if( (*handle)->pInner == NULL )
        {
        new->id = (*handle)->id * 10;
        (*handle)->pInner = new;        
        }
    else if( (*handle)->pInner->pInner == NULL ) 
        {
        new->id = (*handle)->pInner->id * 10;
        (*handle)->pInner->pInner = new;
        }
    }
```

I tried implementing while loops that could iterate through inner nodes until they found NULL one and then creating new node. The problem I'm having is that as I iterate through the nodes, the pointer addresses change and I'm left with one big mess that's no longer working.

I tried making a copy of all the addresses of inner nodes, but then I wasn't able to re-assign them again.

The thing is that I have to add the sub node to the list so I'll be changing various pointer addresses BUT to do that It looks like I need a copy of the list where I could play with it so that the original addresses don't change.

**How do I iterate through the sub nodes and create new ones so that I don't have to hard-code bunch of IF statements ?**

Comment: Could you show us what you tried?

Comment: I think your problem is that you tried to iterate with something like `(*handle) = (*handle)->pInner` where you should have done `tmp = *handle;` and use `tmp = tmp->pInner` in your loop. But I can't really tell as I haven't seen your code.

Comment: Are you sure that your `create_sub_node` function is supposed to work like this? What if you want to create a sub node of `MUSIC` after you've created the `PICTURES` node? If would make more sense if `add_node` would return a node, and then you would pass *that* node into `create_sub_node`, instead of letting it traverse your nodes.

Comment: @Groo That's an interesting observation but later I want to modify the `create_sub_node` function in a way that it will create the sub node under the node that I'll pass the ID of. I think this whole business with returning nodes is going to get messy in the main code if I was to go in that direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My C is a bit rusty but:

```
NODE* tail(NODE* list) {
     if (list == NULL) return NULL;
     NODE* current = list;
     while (current->pInner != NULL) { current = current->pInner; }
     return current;              
}
```

Then your function becomes:

```
void create_sub_node( NODE **handle, char* label )
{
    NODE *new = malloc( sizeof(NODE) );

    new->pNext = NULL;
    new->pInner = NULL;
    strncpy( new->pLabel , label , strlen(label) +1 );   

    NODE* last = tail((*handle));
    new->id = last->id * 10;
    last->pInner = new;        

}
```

Comment: That's more less what I had but I've tried your code (I've added the code from the function call straight into `create_sub_node` and it solved my problem ! Maybe my brain melted a bit from spending too much time on it and I could have been missing something. ALSO A QUESTION: How come  `current = current->pInner` does not modify the original contents of the list ? what I mean is that I know it's a copy of a pointer BUT it still points to something and it looks like that something is modified but not in the original list. why is that ?

Comment: @ShadyProgrammer: `current` is just a local variable that visits the nodes in the list, but doesn't modify them.

Comment: But at the end of my function I did that  `current->pInner = new;` which updated my original list which according to what you say shouldn't do ? I'm confused.

Comment: @ShadyProgrammer At the end of that while loop, `current` will contain the last element in the linked list. `current->pInner` would be `NULL` in this case so you're making `current` point its internal pointer to the `new` node you've created. Also note the `->` operator which dereferences the pointer to modify the contents (since current is a `NODE*`)

Answer (score 1):

Your linked list is more like a tree:

```
|-> MUSIC
|   |-> Punk
|   |-> Funk
|-> VIDEOS
|   |-> Cats
|   |-> Cars
|   |-> Parties
|-> PICTURES
|   |-> 2014
|   |   |-> Skiing
|   |   |-> Trip
|   |   |-> Thksgvg
|   |-> 2015
|   |   |-> Birthday
|   |   |-> Wedding
```

You go to the next node on the vertical line (the next-oldest sibling) via `pNext` and you go one level (the eldest child) deeper via `pInner`. All younger siblings and all children of a node are reachable via the node pointers. You could also kee a pointer to the parant, so that you could walk up, not just down.

You can construct such a tree easily if you have the functions to create nodes and subnodes return the new node:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    NODE *list = NULL;         // list head
    NODE *p;                   // first-generation child 
    NODE *q;                   // second-generation child

    p = add_node(&list, "MUSIC");
        create_sub_node(p, "Punk");
        create_sub_node(p, "Funk");
    p = add_node(&list, "VIDEOS");
        create_sub_node(p, "Cats");
        create_sub_node(p, "Cars");
        create_sub_node(p, "Parties");
    p = add_node(&list, "PICTURES");
    q = create_sub_node(p, "2014");
        create_sub_node(q, "Skiing");
        create_sub_node(q, "Trip");
        create_sub_node(q, "Thksgvg");
    q = create_sub_node(p, "2015");
        create_sub_node(q, "Birthday");
        create_sub_node(q, "Wedding");

    print_nodes(list);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

When you construct the tree, you must change `pNext` for the youngest sibling to the new node, whose `pNext` is `NULL`. Make sure to alter the head of the list only if you append the first node. Likewise, change the `pInner` of a node only when you add the first child.

You usually have to distinguish two cases: first node and subsequent nodes. One technique to combine these cases is to iterate through the list with a pointer to node pointer. That pointer points to the list's or sublist's head first and to the nodes' `pNext` after that, f there are any nodes, that is.

Here are two functions that work with the above `main`:

```
NODE *add_node(NODE **head, const char *label)
{
    NODE **p = head;

    // walk to the end
    while (*p) p = &(*p)->pNext;    

    // append new node
    *p = malloc(sizeof(**p));
    (*p)->pInner = NULL;
    (*p)->pNext = NULL;
    snprintf((*p)->pLabel, sizeof((*p)->pLabel), "%s", label);        

    return (*p);
}

NODE *create_sub_node(NODE *node, const char *label)
{
    NODE **p = &node->pInner;

    // walk to the end
    while (*p) p = &(*p)->pNext;

    // append new node
    *p = malloc(sizeof(**p));    
    (*p)->pInner = NULL;
    (*p)->pNext = NULL;
    snprintf((*p)->pLabel, sizeof((*p)->pLabel), "%s", label);

    return *p;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for above suggestions. I see what you're saying but don't you think that it is much cleaner to instead of creating and returning variables for sub nodes to give the function `create_sub_node` an ID of the node underneath which the sub node is to be created ?

Comment: You can, of course, keep a separate look-up table for ids and nodes. (It should be a hash or something similar fo efficiency.) If you then have a function `node_from_id()` insertion can be done with the same function: `create_sub_node(node_from_is(99), "Mexico")`. The advantage of using the last node is that you don't have to look it up; you already have it.

Comment: Just FYI, I've ditched my original approach of looking at the list as a whole entity and having complex loops to travers it in favor of your approach to look at the head, 1st gen, 2nd gen and so on as separate lists that are linked with each other, it looks like I'm going to have to keep track of new generations and new lists with some sort of dynamic array of pointers. Oh boy, this is going to get hairy ... Thanks for the suggestion again :)